# Python struct unpack multiple bytes with reverse endianess

Tags: python, struct, buffer

So I have a buffer with N bytes and i read them with this, which works but has the reverse endianness from the one i need.

`buffer=struct.unpack_from( 'h'*(N/2), databuff)`

I noticed that endianness is reverse so I wanna experiment with endianess and I use this

`buffer=struct.unpack_from( '<h'*(N/2), databuff)`

However I get this error:

```
>>>buffer=struct.unpack_from( '<h'*1344, databuff) struct.error: bad char in struct format
```

How do I reverse endianness on multiple bytes?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *doesn't work*? What input are you supplying, what output are you getting, and what output do you expect?

Comment: my bad sorry, this is what i get. I have the same input in both codes.




buffer=struct.unpack_from( '<h'*1344, databuff)
struct.error: bad char in struct format

Comment: Eventually I solved the problem by reversing endianness from my hardware side but I am confused on how to do this on python side. So I would like to know being a beginner in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify endianness [at most once](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) in a format, so write

```
buffer=struct.unpack_from('<'+'h'*(N//2), databuff)
```

where the `//` is Python 3 futureproofing.